# Invalid assembly file format

Tags: c#, network-programming, .net-assembly

In a login program I work with, remote users began having issues logging in, with an error message of:

> Invalid assembly file format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141D).

I tried restarting the server and remote server, but it did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The user noticed that the mapped drive which connected to the apps server would keep mounting and dismounting, they checked network traffic and noticed one of the connected computers were behaving oddly (data transfer would spike up and down).  When they disconnected that computer from the network, it resolved the login issues they were having.